# How to set spark configuration to reduce shuffling when working with k-means clustering?

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I know that there's a lot 'How to tune your Spark jobs' etc. blog posts and threads out there, but unfortunately I aim to work with a built-in clustering module in pyspark (k-means), so suggestions like 'use reduceByKey instead of groupByKey' still don't help me much, as I can't really control what's going on in the code after I call the clustering algorithm and apparently, it seems to consume a **huge amount of disk space for shuffling** (running on a DataFrame of size 25 Gb).

Is there any way, like suggested configuration setup (executor memory etc.) that I can use to bypass this issue? I'd prefer to keep the used disk space for tmp files under 100-150 Gb if possible.

On a general note, I'd appreciate any info from anyone who actually **used one of the clustering algorithms from the mllib on big data** (or big-ish, like mine). **Were you able to avoid extensive shuffling somehow and if so how?**

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use Spark for clustering *at all*. It does not make sense to use it. The good non-Spark implementations are 100x times faster, and when your data does not fit into memory anymore, just use a sample - it will be as accurate as the entire data set. No reason to pay the 100x penalty of Spark.

Comment: What 'good non-Spark' implementations are you referring to? I'm working in python at the moment so the next thing that comes to my mind is scikit-learn.

Comment: how many cores and RAM you have?

Comment: 48 cores and 252 Gb

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if sklearn will be faster than Spark even with just one core. If you want to use all cores, use this (it's the fastest KMeans I know, but C and very specialized) https://github.com/ghamerly/fast-kmeans if you want a fast Java version, use KMeansSort in ELKI (that may be easier and more efficient to access from Scala, if you do your preprocessing there).

Comment: This interesting article benchmarked many implementations, and Spark was one of the worst (naive algorithm, high overhead): Kriegel, H. P., Schubert, E., & Zimek, A. (2017). The (black) art of runtime evaluation: Are we comparing algorithms or implementations?. Knowledge and Information Systems, 52(2), 341-378.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna check out this article, looks interesting indeed. Finally I've opted to use sklearn although I'm familiar with Java, I did a bit of random fragmentation of my dataset as well, so I actually ended up doing an iterative clustering approach on subsets.

Answer (score 0):

you have ample amount of resource 48 cores and 252 Gb so use if your dataframe name is df then before running the k means code please cache your data you can use persist or cache method for the same:

```
df.persist()
df.count()
```

or

```
df.cache()
df.count()
```

we need to perform some action to cache the dataframe in the memory after this your shuffling will be reduced definitely and please do let me know it this works for you or not

Comment: Hey, so I tried it out but it seems like that I still end up with a lot of temporary files from shuffling, regardless of this or the amount of RAM I designate for the executors and the driver in the config. Maybe I should have played a bit more with the spark.shuffle.memoryFraction and spark.storage.memoryFraction but I'm afraid that still wouldn't solve my issue in this case.

Comment: repartition with number of columns in the parameter will also help and also you need to see that there are not too much pending operations when action is performed that also result in too much shuffling its better to write the table and read after certain number of joins and filters that reduce shuffling